# Can you damage the proximity sensor if you keep it always on?

Tags: hardware, sensors, proximity-sensor

If you keep the proximity sensor always on (like for applications that turn on the screen when you tap the sensor a few times) is there a risk to damage it?

I'm assuming that the sensor works only in certain situations (e.g. phone rings and sensor is activated to see if phone is in pocket, during a call to detect proximity to the head etc) so I'm wondering if it's OK to keep the sensor on all the time.

Comment: Just one data point... on an older phone I wrote an app that left the proximity sensor on all the time at night (to easy log when I got in and out of bed) and I never had any issues.  On my model it was just a (very dim) red LED which probably has a longer life than the phone as a whole.

Answer (score 5):

The sensor is always on, so there's no higher risk of damage if an app uses it.

Comment: It's always on?! No matter the type of sensor or phone?

Comment: It wouldn't make much sense to turn it on/off. It's a very low power sensor.